# Count LOC per developer in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I installed SonarQube server in docker and analyzed first project.
There is metric named LoC (lines of code) in project.
How can i aggregate it per developer (git author), i want to see the impact of each developer in project?

Comment: Sounds to me like a bad metric. Bad metric leads to setting up bad goals. Bad goals lead to developers writing bad code to look better in bad metrics. Been there, seen that.

Comment: I get your point. The main point is that i already have way to check code quality + code reviews. I want to aggregate this by language. I want to see impact for project by this metric, for example half of JS code was created by this developer. May be you can advice another type of metric?